# pgfplots ybar dashed outline

Tags: pgfplots

When creating a bargraph with `ybar`, the last added plot has a `dashed` outline and I don't seem to understand why.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines=left,
            xmajorgrids,
            ymajorgrids,
            xmin=0,
            xmax=7,
            ymin=60,
            ymax=80,
            bar width=5mm
            ]
            \addplot+[ybar,mark=0,fill=black!80,draw=black]
                coordinates {
                (1,77.071)
            };
            \addplot+[ybar,mark=0,fill=black!30,draw=black]
                coordinates {
                (2,70.256)
            };
            \addplot+[ybar,mark=0,fill=black!30,draw=black]
                coordinates {
                (3,65.383)
            };
            \addplot+[ybar,mark=0,fill=black!30,draw=black]
                coordinates {
                (4,66.077)
            };
            \addplot+[ybar,mark=0,fill=black!30,draw=black]
                coordinates {
                (5,75.808)
            };
            \addplot+[ybar,mark=0,fill=black!10,draw=black]
                coordinates {
                (6,77.635)
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image: bargraph strange behaviour]

Although, when I "add" less plots, this issue disappears, as follows:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines=left,
            xmajorgrids,
            ymajorgrids,
            xmin=0,
            xmax=7,
            ymin=60,
            ymax=80,
            bar width=5mm
            ]
            \addplot+[ybar,mark=0,fill=black!80,draw=black]
                coordinates {
                (1,77.071)
            };
            \addplot+[ybar,mark=0,fill=black!30,draw=black]
                coordinates {
                (2,70.256)(3,65.383)(4,66.077)(5,75.808)
            };
            \addplot+[ybar,mark=0,fill=black!10,draw=black]
                coordinates {
                (6,77.635)
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image: normal bargraph]

Comment: If you use for the last plot `\addplot+[ybar,mark=0,fill=black!10,draw=black,solid]
                coordinates {
                (6,77.635)
            };` it will be solid as well. I believed (without explicitly checking) that this behavior is controlled by the `cycle list`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior is controlled by the `cycle list`. If you look at the pgfplots manual at p. 214 you'll find

[image]

This explains why the 6th plot has dashed lines. One way to cure this is to add `solid` to the plot, or you could just create and use your own cycle list.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{Syphirint}{
   fill=black!80,draw=black,solid,mark=none\\
   fill=black!30,draw=black,solid,mark=none\\
   fill=black!30,draw=black,solid,mark=none\\
   fill=black!30,draw=black,solid,mark=none\\
   fill=black!30,draw=black,solid,mark=none\\
   fill=black!10,draw=black,solid,mark=none\\
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[cycle list name=Syphirint,
            axis lines=left,
            xmajorgrids,
            ymajorgrids,
            xmin=0,
            xmax=7,
            ymin=60,
            ymax=80,
            bar width=5mm
            ]
            \addplot+[ybar]
                coordinates {
                (1,77.071)
            };
            \addplot+[ybar]
                coordinates {
                (2,70.256)
            };
            \addplot+[ybar]
                coordinates {
                (3,65.383)
            };
            \addplot+[ybar]
                coordinates {
                (4,66.077)
            };
            \addplot+[ybar]
                coordinates {
                (5,75.808)
            };
            \addplot+[ybar]
                coordinates {
                (6,77.635)
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]